# Basic Subnet Mask Calculator + A Little Extra

Tags: c, bitwise, c11

For my Networking class, we learned about subnetting and subnet masks.

I decided to write a little "calculator" (a generous term) that when given `n`-many network bits, generates a 32-bit subnet mask, then displays it as octets, and as binary with the leading 0s removed. Example `main`:

```
int main() {
    int nNetworkBits = 26;
    BitField mask = generateSubnetMask(nNetworkBits);

    printf("%u\n", mask);  // Prints 4294967232
    printf("\n");

    printOctets(mask);  // Prints 255.255.255.192
    printf("\n");

    printBinary(mask);  // Prints 11111111111111111111111111000000
    printf("\n");
}
```

I'm pretty terrible at C, so I'd like comments on anything and everything that is worth mentioning. I figured out the math/bitshifting as I was writing the code, so if I'm doing anything "roundabout", I'd definitely like to know about it.

The only thing that I don't need advice on is my "abuse" of `printf`. I know I should be accumulating a string in a buffer then returning that buffer instead of printing directly from the functions. That's a pain in C though and detracted from the main problem that I was trying to solve, so I decided to go for the quick and dirty way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>


#define TOTAL_BITS 32
#define N_OCTETS ((TOTAL_BITS / 8))

typedef uint32_t BitField;


BitField generateOctetMask(int octetI) {
    return (BitField)0xFF << (octetI * 8);
}

BitField generateSubnetMask(int nNetworkBits) {
    int nHostBits = TOTAL_BITS - nNetworkBits;
    return ~0 << nHostBits;  // TODO: Cast 0 to BitField?
}

void printOctets(BitField maskAddress) {
    for (int octetN = N_OCTETS - 1; octetN >= 0; octetN--) {
        BitField mask = generateOctetMask(octetN);
        printf("%d", (maskAddress & mask) >> (octetN * 8));

        if (octetN > 0) {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
}

void printBinary(BitField n) {
    bool areDropping = true;  // So we can drop leading 0s.

    for (BitField mask = 1u << 31; mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {
        bool isSet = n & mask;

        if (isSet) {
            areDropping = false;
            printf("1");

        } else if (!areDropping) {
            printf("0");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int nNetworkBits = 26;
    BitField mask = generateSubnetMask(nNetworkBits);

    printf("%u\n", mask);  // Prints 4294967232
    printf("\n");

    printOctets(mask);  // Prints 255.255.255.192
    printf("\n");

    printBinary(mask);  // Prints 11111111111111111111111111000000
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Prefer `const` to `#define`

For constants such as `TOTAL_BITS`, it's generally better to use a named `const` value rather than a `#define`.  The primary reason is that the `const` definition enforces type checking, while the macro does not.  However, see the next suggestion.

### Use `sizeof` for portability

The code currently contains these lines:

```
#define TOTAL_BITS 32
#define N_OCTETS ((TOTAL_BITS / 8))

typedef uint32_t BitField;
```

However, I think I'd define everything instead as `const` values all derived from the type.  That is, I'd suggest this:

```
typedef uint32_t BitField;
const int BitFieldOctets = sizeof(BitField);
const int BitFieldBits = 8 * BitFieldOctets;
```

### Think carefully about signed vs. unsigned

If `generateSubnetMask` is passed a negative number, what should it do?  I'd suggest that the passed number should be `unsigned` instead of `int` and that the value could be checked to make sure it does not exceed the naximum number of bits.

### Be careful when shifting negative values

By default, constants are `int`, so this code:

```
return ~0 << nHostBits;
```

Should probably instead be written like this:

```
return ~0u << nHostBits;
```

### Avoid pointless recalculations

The code has this function:

```
void printOctets(BitField maskAddress) {
    for (int octetN = BitFieldOctets - 1; octetN >= 0; octetN--) {
        BitField mask = generateOctetMask(octetN);
        printf("%d", (maskAddress & mask) >> (octetN * 8));

        if (octetN > 0) {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
}
```

This is more complex than it needs to be.  First, the mask can be generated just once for the high byte and then shifted, eliminating a number of calculations that don't need to be done:

```
void printOctets(BitField maskAddress) {
    BitField mask = generateOctetMask(BitFieldOctets - 1);
    for (unsigned i=BitFieldOctets; i; --i) {
        printf("%d", (maskAddress & mask) >> (BitFieldBits - 8));
        maskAddress <<= 8;
        if (i != 1) {
            printf(".");
        }
    }
}
```

This works by keeping the mask in place over the most significant byte and then shifting the address to the left each iteration.  An alternative would be to use a `union` as the `BitField` type to allow access to each byte very simply.  That approach, however, requires that you account for the endian-ness of your machine, which this code does not.

### Consider restructuring for simplicity and clarity

The `printBinary` code is currently like this:

```
void printBinary(BitField n) {
    bool areDropping = true;  // So we can drop leading 0s.

    for (BitField mask = 1u << 31; mask > 0; mask >>= 1) {
        bool isSet = n & mask;

        if (isSet) {
            areDropping = false;
            printf("1");

        } else if (!areDropping) {
            printf("0");
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, I'd break this into two different loops: the first to skip leading zeroes and the second to actually print the bits.  Here's one way to do that:

```
void printBinary(BitField n) {
    BitField mask = 1u << (BitFieldBits - 1);
    // skip leading zeroes
    for (; mask && !(mask & n); mask >>= 1);
    // print all other bits
    for (; mask; mask >>= 1) {
        putchar(n & mask ? '1' : '0');
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm using the named constants rather than the "magic number" 31.